# Error in inserting comparison 'last modifed date' record between 2 tables into another table

Tags: mysql, compare, sql-insert

status_tb

1st change

```
 +----+----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+
 | id | status   | description | state_id |  last_modified_on  |
 +----+----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+
 |  1 |     new  | north       | 1        | 2018-10-10 12:30:00|
 |  2 |   assign | south       | 2        | 2018-10-10 13:30:00|
 |  3 |Postponed | east        | 2        | 2018-10-10 14:30:00|
 |  4 |    Fixed | west        | 3        | 2018-10-10 15:30:00|
 | 35 |     Test | South-test  | 4        | 2018-10-10 20:30:00|<-1st try
 +----+----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+
```

2nd change

```
 +----+----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+
 | id | status   | description | state_id |  last_modified_on  |
 +----+----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+
 |  1 |     new  | north       | 1        | 2018-10-10 12:30:00|
 |  2 |   assign | south       | 2        | 2018-10-10 13:30:00|
 |  3 |Postponed | east        | 2        | 2018-10-10 24:30:00|
 |  4 |    Fixed | west        | 3        | 2018-10-10 15:30:00|
 | 35 |  Try_OLD | Tried_OLD   | 4        | 2018-10-10 22:22:22|<-2nd try
 +----+----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+
```

status_backup_tb (old values(b4 change) fall into **backup** by trigger after update in status_tb)

```
 +----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+----------------+
 |backup_id | id | status   | description | state_id |last_modified_on|
 +----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+----------------+
 |  1       |  1 |new       | north       | 1        |2018-10-10 12:30:00
 |  2       |  2 |assign    | south       | 2        |2018-10-10 13:30:00
 |  3       |  3 |Postponed | east        | 2        |2018-10-10 24:30:00
 |  4       |  4 | Fixed    | west        | 3        |2018-10-10 15:30:00
 |  7       |  35| Rejected | Testing     | 4        |2018-10-10 11:00:00
 +----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+

 +----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+----------------+
 |backup_id | id | status   | description| state_id |last_modified_on|
 +----------+----+----------+------------+----------+----------------+
 |  1       |  1 |new       | north      | 1        |2018-10-10 12:30:00
 |  2       |  2 |assign    | south      | 2        |2018-10-10 13:30:00
 |  3       |  3 |Postponed | east       | 2        |2018-10-10 24:30:00
 |  4       |  4 | Fixed    | west       | 3        |2018-10-10 15:30:00
 |  7       |  35| Rejected | Testing    | 4        |2018-10-10 11:00:00
 |  8       |  35| Test     | South-test | 4        |2018-10-10 20:30:00<
```

**1st time** I execute my query to insert-select my comparison values

```
|new_id | id |Column_changed| Old_value|New_value | Modified_on       |
+-------+----+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------+
|1      | 35 | status       |Rejected  | Test     |2018-10-10 20:30:00|
|2      | 35 |description   |Testing   |South-test|2018-10-10 20:30:00| 
+-------+----+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------+
```

**2nd time** I execute my query to insert-select my comparison values

The **modified date** on the 1st modified change does back to `2018-10-10 22:22:22` instead of staying `2018-10-10 20:30:00` when i apply change on the  same id

**Actual Result**(error)

```
|new_id| id |Column_changed| Old_value  |New_value |Modified_on        |
+------+----+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|1     | 35 | status       |Rejected    |Test      |2018-10-10 22:22:22|<
|2     | 35 |description   | Testing    |South-test|2018-10-10 22:22:22|< 
+------+----+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|3     | 35 | status       | Test       | Try_OLD  |2018-10-10 22:22:22|
|4     | 35 |description   | South-test |Tried_OLD |2018-10-10 22:22:22| 
+------+----+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
|new_id | id |Column_changed| Old_value |New_value |Modified_on        |
+------+----+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|1     | 35 | status       |Rejected    |Test      |2018-10-10 20:30:00|<
|2     | 35 |description   | Testing    |South-test|2018-10-10 20:30:00|< 
+------+----+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|3     | 35 | status       | Test       | Try_OLD  |2018-10-10 22:22:22|
|4     | 35 |description   | South-test |Tried_OLD |2018-10-10 22:22:22| 
+------+----+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
```

new_id: 1 and 2 are from the lst change, 3 and 4 are from the 2nd change

SQL

```
INSERT INTO audit_status_tb (id, Column_changed, Old_value, New_value) 

SELECT 
  distinct s.id, 
  'status' AS Column_changed, 
  s.status AS Old_value, 
  b.status AS New_value,
  s.last_modified_on 
  FROM status_tb AS s
  JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
    ON b.id = s.id AND 
    b.status <> s.status

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
   distinct s.id, 
   'description' AS Column_changed, 
   s.description AS Old_value, 
   b.description AS New_value,
   s.last_modified_on 
     FROM status_tb AS s
     JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
     ON b.id = s.id AND 
        b.description <> s.description

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  distinct  s.id, 
  'state_id' AS Column_changed, 
  s.state_id AS Old_value, 
  b.state_id AS New_value,
  s.last_modified_on 
     FROM status_tb AS s
     JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
   ON b.id = s.id AND 
   b.state_id <> s.state_id
```

Comment: Why are you deleting all the rows and then inserting again. There is no way you can retain the old time value using this workflow.

Comment: Sorry was testing something, forgot to remove it, but I still cant get corresponding modified date for the given insert values...

Comment: Whenever there is such a big question, it is advisable to set a fiddle, otherwise it is hard to keep track of. Please setup here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/  and once done, share the link.